# PostgreSQL: Looped call to procedure floods Transaction Cash Memory

Tags: postgresql, transactions, procedure

If we have a procedure like this:

```
create procedure check_all_accounts()
as $code$
declare 
    id varchar;
    rec record; 
begin
    for rec in select acc.id from main.account acc where acc.type_id = 'ACT'
    loop        
        raise notice '%: Checking Account %', substring(clock_timestamp()::varchar, 1, 19), rec.id;
    call main.check_and_cleanup(rec.id);    
    -- commit; -- Does not work within procedure
    end loop;
exception 
    when others then
    raise notice 'Failed for Account %s. Error: %', rec.id, sqlerrm;
end; $code$ language plpgsql;
```

It runs some 52'000 loops for me and then the server complains as the Transaction Cash memory is full.
If I run this as such block it works as `commit`is allowed.

```
do $code$
declare
    id varchar;
    rec record; 
begin
    for rec in select acc.id from main.account acc where acc.type_id = 'ACT'
    loop        
        raise notice '%: Checking Account %', substring(clock_timestamp()::varchar, 1, 19), rec.id;
        call main.check_and_cleanup(rec.id);    
        commit; -- Commit is allowed/needed here
    end loop;
end; $code$
```

How can I overcome this issue as I need to run this from a single procedure?
I hoped for all loops to go though, but it failes after transaction cash gets filled.

The exact error message details as given by `get stacked diagnostics`:

- returned_sqlstate=`53200`
- message_text=`out of shared memory`

Comment: "*the Transaction Cash memory is full*" - there is no such error message in Postgres. Please **[edit]** your question and add the **exact** and complete error message you get.

Comment: A `commit` **is** allowed in a procedure as long as the _caller_ didn't start a transaction.

Comment: The usual way to deal with performance (and other problems) cause by looping over a result it to remove the loop and use a set-based approach (the way SQL was meant to be used).

Comment: Thanks for the hints @a_horse_with_no_name! Will put actual exact message... and provide more details

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Would you eventually have an example of how to do this: "A commit is allowed in a procedure as long as the caller didn't start a transaction.". I mean, I simply have my procedure `check_all_accounts()`, there are loops inside, bit if I try to add `commit`, if I run `call check_all_accounts();` it yells straight back at me because of that commit... So I should I run this to avoid overflooding the shared memory? Any ideas?

Comment: The exact error message details as given by `get stacked diagnostics`: `returned_sqlstate=53200
message_text=out of shared memory`

Answer (score 0):

After lot of back and forth... this version finally worked!

```
create procedure check_all_accounts()
as $code$
declare 
    rec record; 
    e_message_text      varchar;    
    e_returned_sqlstate varchar;
    e_exception_detail  varchar;
    e_exception_context varchar;
begin
    for rec in select acc.id from main.account acc where acc.type_id = 'ACT'
    loop        
        raise notice '%: Checking Account %', substring(clock_timestamp()::varchar, 1, 19), rec.id;
        begin
            call main.check_and_cleanup(rec.id);
        exception 
            when others then
                get stacked diagnostics
                    e_message_text      := MESSAGE_TEXT,    
                    e_returned_sqlstate := RETURNED_SQLSTATE,
                    e_exception_detail  := PG_EXCEPTION_DETAIL,
                    e_exception_context := PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;
            raise notice 'Failed for Account!. ERROR: e_message_text=%, e_returned_sqlstate=%, e_exception_detail=%, e_exception_context=%', 
                rec.id, e_message_text, e_returned_sqlstate, e_exception_detail, e_exception_context;
        end;
        commit; -- It works happily after begin/end block!
    end loop;
end; $code$ language plpgsql;
```